# c# calling function parameters

Tags: c#, function, web-services, parameter-passing

I have developed a method (GetDServices) of a webservice , which calls a function (GetResource) that returns a string result.

In the first call to the function, the value of the Culture parameter is 'ca-ES', and retrieves it perfectly.

The second time I call the method, the function receives the parameter with the value 'en-US', but the value of the first call 'ca-ES' remains.

I do not understand why this happens.
I have debugged and the value of the method call arrives correctly.

If i restart, first time run well.

I edit this code, and now post full code.

After test, i tryed to assign new vars (test and test2) and i saw that when i call the method since assignation (test & test2) running well, but when i call method from array assignation, in the second call remain first value.

**My method:**

```
  [WebMethod]
  #region GetServices
  public ResultDTO GetServices(
        LoginDTO login,
        string enterprise,
        string culture,
        out List<Services> Services 
        )
  {
      Bootstrapper.TryInit();
      LogHelper.DumpParams("WS.GetServices", login, enterprise);

      // Inicialización de salida.
      Services = new List<Services>();
      try
      {
          // LOGIN VALIDATION
          User user;
          var result = ValidationHelper.ValidateLogin(login, out user);

          if (result != null)
          {
              return LogHelper.DumpResult("WS.GetServices", result);
          }
          // LOGIN VALIDATION END

          // QUERY SERVICES
          var queryservices = Bootstrapper.Context.GetRepository<Service, long>()
              .Query().Where(x => x.EnterpriseServiceRelationVigence.Any(y => y.Enterprise.NIF == enterprise));

          if (queryservices == null)
          {
              return LogHelper.DumpResult("WS.GetServices", new ResultDTO(ErrorCodes.SERVICES_NOT_FOUND));
          }

          // this vars has correct value after assignation
          string test = culture; // <-  here First time has "ca-ES" and second time has "en-US" 
          string test2 = GetResource(culture, "sample" );  // <-  here First time has "ca-Es" and second time has "en-US" 


          Services = queryservices.Select(x => new Services
          {
              IdService =  x.Id,
              Name = x.Name,
              ShortDescription = GetResource(test, x.ResourceKey + "Description"),
              Description = GetResource(test, x.ResourceKey + "Comment"),
              ImageButton = x.ImageButton,
              ImageButtonDisabled = x.ImageButtonDisabled,
              ImageButtonHome = x.ImageButtonHome,
              ColorTextoHome = x.ColorTextoHome,
          }
              ).ToList();

          return LogHelper.DumpResult("WS.GetServices", new ResultDTO());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Logger.Log.Error(() => ex.ToString());
          return LogHelper.DumpResult("WS.GetServices", new ResultDTO(ErrorCodes.GENERIC_ERROR));
      }
  }
  #endregion
```

**My function:**

```
  static string GetResource(string Culture, string ResourceKey)
  {

    // When this function its called, from test2 assignation running well.
    // but when this function its called from 
    //      ShortDescription = GetResource(test, x.ResourceKey + "Description"), 
    // or 
    //      Description = GetResource(test, x.ResourceKey + "Comment"),     
    // then remained the value of first call.


      if (Culture.IsNullOrEmpty()) { Culture = "es-ES"; }

      var queryservices = Bootstrapper.Context.GetRepository<Resource, string>()
          .Query().Where(x => x.ResourceKey == ResourceKey && x.CultureKey == Culture);

      if (!queryservices.IsNullOrEmpty()) // Usuari Generic
      {
          return queryservices.Select(x => x.ResourceValue).FirstOrDefault();
      }

      return string.Empty;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to do debugging? What is the value of `Culture`  before (re)assigning it `es-ES`?

Comment: `Culture.IsNullOrEmpty()`?? is that an extension?

Comment: @Fredou, that's `string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture)` I believe?

Comment: @Fredou, I might be? ohh really ... see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Such a thing would never work as a member method, because null.IsNullOrEmpty() would throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Zeus depend on the implementation and Rahul yup, i think i need 0. a coffee and 1. visual studio and LordRick3dfx can you post the extension method?

Comment: `The second time I call the method, the function receives the parameter with the value 'en-US', but the value of the first call 'ca-ES' remains.` I am unclear what this sentence means.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can post complete code of the `GetDServices` method body, (assuming the original value of the `culture` coming to the method is correct) check if you have any **re-assignments of the `culture` variable** inside it before calling `GetResource` i.e. the code of the following

```
// Inicialization
 ...
// Login validation
 ...
// End Login Validation
 ...
```

Comment: The content marked with ... is irrelevant, so I have not written it.
Debugging I have seen that the variable "culture" receives as a parameter in the method call, a value of "ca-ES".
Just enter the function value is "ca-ES", but in the second call to the function, the value of the parameter, is not updated with the value of the call.
I will continue testing.
I have doubts about whether the function is well defined.

Comment: One of the ways to check is to configure Fiddler as your proxy and see the value of the `culture` in the payload.